# Using Logo as a link to home page

Tags: html, css

I need to have the logo as a link to the ideas page (Which is the home page) in HTML and CSS3 this is what I have.  What do I need to add please?

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <img id="logo" src="Photos/logo.jpg"  alt="My logo">
        </div>
        <div id="navigation_container">
 <!-- the body -->
        <div class="rectangle">
 <!-- the navigation links -->
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="Index.html">&#10029; IDEAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/workshop.html">&#10029; WORKSHOP</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/Tips.html">&#10029; TIPS</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/Digital_Paper.html">&#10029; DIGITAL PAPER</a></li>
            </ul>
 <!-- end the body -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="SITE_LINK"><img id="logo" src="Photos/logo.jpg"  alt="My logo"></a>
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

update your html like the below

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="ideas.html"><img id="logo" src="Photos/logo.jpg"  alt="My logo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score -1):

You write your code should be like this

```
    <div id="logo">
     <a href="">
      <img id="logo" src="Photos/logo.jpg"  alt="My logo">
     </a>  
    </div>
```